# same code (C) not working on terminal, but working on IDE

Tags: c, gcc, netbeans

(C code)
I have made an AVL tree, its working on netbeans(with gcc compiler plug-in)
When I run the SAME code in the linux terminal(compiled with gcc too) I got an ¨Segmentation fault (core dumped)¨error, how is this possible?

The error appears when I load the data from a text file into the structures.

```
Node* load(Node* T, char* fileName) {


FILE* ptFile;

char myString[200]; 

char* ape1 = NULL; //data to insert on the node structure
char* ape2 = NULL;
char* nomb = NULL;
char* mail = NULL;
char* ciudad = NULL;
char* pais = NULL;
int fono = 0;


ptFile = fopen(fileName, "r"); 

if (ptFile == NULL) { 

    printf("ERROR file missing\n");
    exit(1);
}

fgets(myString, 200, ptFile);
while (feof(ptFile) == 0) { // IF I COMMENT THIS LOOP THE ERROR DISAPEARS...BUT IM NOT GETTING THE DATA LOADED OBVIOUSLY



   //HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR APPEARS
    ape1 = strdup(strtok(myString, ",\n"));

    if(myString != NULL){
    ape2 = strdup(strtok(NULL, ",\n"));
    nomb = strdup(strtok(NULL, ",\n"));
    mail = strdup(strtok(NULL, ",\n"));
    fono = atoi(strtok(NULL, ",\n"));
    ciudad = strdup(strtok(NULL, ",\n"));
    pais = strdup(strtok(NULL, ",\n"));


        T = insert(T, ape1, ape2, nomb, mail, fono, ciudad, pais); 
    }        

    fgets(myString, 200, ptFile);



}
fclose(ptFile);
return T;
```

}

this function works perfectly fine on netbenas, why is it not working when I run this on terminal?
what I’m doing wrong?... insert function works fine when I manually insert de data.
thanks.

Comment: Is there something missing?  You appear to have a mis-matched bracket after the line `T = insert(...`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
ape1 = strdup(strtok(myString, ",\n"));

if(myString != NULL){//always TRUE
```

change to

```
char *temp = strtok(myString, ",\n");
if(temp != NULL){
    ape1 = strdup(temp);
    ....
```